# Как с помощью JS проверить нажат ли checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html5

Всем привет! Имеется код:

```
<body>
<?header('location: settime.php');?>
<script>
function selectAll(btn) {
    btn.checkValue = (btn.checkValue != "on")? "on" : "off";
    var value = btn.checkValue == "on";

    var boxes = document.querySelectorAll("table input[type='checkbox']");            

    for ( var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++ ) {
        boxes[i].checked = value;
    }
  }
</script>
<input type="button" value="Block" onClick='location.href="delete.php"'>
<input type="button" value="Unblock"  onClick='location.href="unblock.php"'>
<input type="button" value="LogOut" onClick='location.href="login.php"'>
<button onclick="selectAll(this)"> Select All</button> 
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Last login</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
  <?php 
  $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');
  $query = "SELECT*FROM users WHERE id > 0";
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die (mysqli_error($db));
  for ( $data = []; $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); $data[] = $row );
  $result='';
  foreach ($data as $elem) 
  {
  $result.='<tr>';
      $result.='<td><input type="checkbox" id="elem"></td>';
      $result.='<td>'.$elem['username'].'</td>';
      $result.='<td>'.$elem['lastlogin'].'</td>';
      $result.='<td>'.$elem['Activity'].'</td>';
  $result.='</tr>';
  }
  echo $result;
  ?>
</table>
```

и сама страница HTML: https://ibb.co/cc190q
Как проверить связан ли checkbox с соответствующей строкой, допустим, при выборе чекбокса в строке с именем qwe и нажатие кнопки block должен появиться alert: (qwe was blocked). Если несколько выбрать флажков, то, допустим : alert(qwe and asd were blocked).
Спасибо за идеи и помощь!

Comment: покажите нормальный код без php так невозможно прочитать

Comment: `element.checked`?